# findViewById function using string variables

Tags: android

i am currently facing a problem, is it possible to use the function "`findViewById()`" like this?

```
String[] names{ "a", "b"};
findViewById(R.drawable.names[0]);
```

Comment: No, findViewById() accepts int (View id) as parameter.

Comment: `findViewById` and `R.drawable`? seems legit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Just so you know, you can only call `findViewById` on `R.id` types. Thus, your code is bound to fail since you're calling it on `R.drawable` types.

Try `getIdentifier()`. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(names[0], "drawable", getPackageName());
findViewById(resourceId);
```

Note: The Android Documentation says:

> use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to
>   retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

In this case, it'll probably be better if you defined an array of `int`, and those contained the ids of the `drawable` resources.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you cannot do that, but instead there is a work around for that. Try something like this:-

```
String[] names{ "a", "b"};
int drawableId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(names[0], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
findViewById(drawableId);
```

Where `this` is an Activity, written just to clarify.

In case you want a `String` in **strings.xml** or an `identifier` of a UI element, substitute the "drawable"

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfResource", "id", this.getPackageName());
```

I must warn you, this way of obtaining identifiers is really slow, use only where needed.

Comment: I don't think your answer was wrong or irrelevant. So I'll neutralize the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() accept int not string. So you can use like..

```
int[] txtViewIdsform1;
txtViewIdsform1 = new int[] { R.drawable.txt_phone1, R.drawable.txt_phone2,
                R.drawable.txt_fax, R.drawable.txt_contact_name, R.drawable.txt_contact_ph};
```

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be done

You can do it other way like

```
int[] ids={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b};
findViewById(ids[0]);
```